# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'UnitMeasure'

Tags: sql, database

I dont know what I've done wrong but here is the complete action I'm trying to complete.

```
Update Production.UnitMeasure
SET Name = 'Square Feet'
Where Production.UnitMeasure
```

This is the error im getting..

```
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'UnitMeasure'.
```

Comment: Your update statement is incomplete. Whos is the table and what is your conditions? Production is a scheme or a table? What is UnitMeasure?

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause is malformed. It should evaluate to something, like this:

```
Update Production.UnitMeasure
SET Name = 'Square Feet'
Where Field = 'some value'
```